# Why wont the button disappear?

Tags: android

Im trying to develop an Android app, and one of the features when hitting a button, should be that the button disappears. This, however does not work, can anyone explain me why? Thanks!

```
    Button StartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    StartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
                View thisButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
                thisButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
```

Comment: You should name your variable using camel case. `StartButton` should be `startButton`

Comment: Is your code in the onCreate method of the Activity?

Comment: @X3Btel Yes, in fact it is... Thats how it is supposed to be, right?

Comment: Yes, it should be there. Did you try  logging or debugging? To log type log.e("onCreate", "Button clicked") after the set visibility

Comment: @HåvardNygård : didi you get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry for answering my own question, but there was a problem with the studio, and not the app. Sorry for making such a big deal out of nothing. Thanks for all answers. They helped me alot when setting up a new project :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
    Button StartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);        
        StartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: oO, do you debug or put a log inside onClick to see if the method are reached?

Comment: I will do that now :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize the button again. Just pass the same button.Try with this :

```
Button StartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    StartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
                StartButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
StartButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: This isn't very helpful in explaining why or how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Button StartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    StartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
```

or make button final and onclick change visibility.

```
final Button StartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
 StartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                    StartButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });
```

Comment: can you please debug and confirm that on click listener is getting called. @HåvardNygård

Comment: Quick, maybe stupid question, how can i use the debugger to check? Tried the Log.d method to log.. Fairly new, thanks.

Comment: ohk it is fine everyone is a newbee at some point . https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html check this

Comment: have you get Log message for Log.d that you used? if not than there is chance that your method is not called

Answer (score 0):

please use the button. You only need  to hide the particular button

```
  StartButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: That does so i have to use the Final keyword on the StartButton

Comment: Move declaration of the view out of the onCreate method. at the beginning of the class make Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton); Then later use  directly startButton

Comment: @HåvardNygård : didi you get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
    Button StartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);        
    StartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```